# Button Function not working after testing on android build

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Button works fine on unity, but has problems when built and tested on android

I have a button which basically just picks up an item and puts it down whenever it is pressed, and it works just fine on Unity, but when I do an android build and send it to my phone to test, when I press the button it displays the animation but I cant seem to pick the item up anymore and I can't seem to find the problem.

[image: Item pick up code]

[image: Item grab code]

[image: Button Inspector]

Comment: Add your code as text using the code-block function in the question editor instead of relying solely on screenshots.

Answer (score 0):

Fist of all:

- You can add block of code as this `var codeInImageMessage = "Hard to read"`>
- You don't need to test if it `true` or `false`, it is a C#
  and not a JS.

Possible problem

- Scene can have different order of object. So I would recommend not use transform.child and set reference from Inspector with `[SerializableField] private GameObject nameOfThisObject;`
- Try to set Sphere collider to bigger size to test it.
- Set view in unity to the same resolution as your mobile phone.
- Build with debugging enabled and go step by step and look for error.